# Source for quote - "Wherever you look there’s something to be seen"

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara, performance-entertainment, popular-culture

In the film [Anger Management](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anger_Management_(film)), Dr. Buddy Rydell (Jack Nicholson) says: “the Talmud says ‘wherever you look there’s something to be seen’”.

Any ideas what passage this quote is in reference to?

Comment: הרואה בוטה בקלטקלה יזיר עצמו מן היין

Comment: ??? https://www.sefaria.org/Sotah.2a.5?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi

Comment: @kouty and Dr. Shmuel Doubtful; only a deeper understanding and interpretation of that line could fit.

Comment: IME quotes from "the Talmud" in pop culture are rarely real.

Comment: @DoubleAA Sometimes they end up being Yiddish quips, sayings, or sometimes (though rarely) they're from other Jewish works.

Comment: @DoubleAA Second one today, too.

Answer (score 0):

If we assume this isn’t a Talmudic quote, but a Jewish one:

> במקום אשר ישים האדם נפשו שם ימצאנה

Quoted in Otzar Hameshalim 1270, from פניני המליצות, ה

——
This is the parallel I saw:

- Wherever you look - ישים אדם נפשו
- There’s something to be seen - שם ימצאנה

Comment: I don't undrestand how you translate this statement in a practical language

Comment: Same thing could be said about the op

Comment: the OP is about the fact that any situation gives you an oportunity to learn something.

Comment: The answer seems tot say that if you choose something, it is for your.